# How to generate a JWT at userlogin in Okta portal using Okta as OIDC provider. I want to assume an AWS role using this JWT

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, okta, api-gateway

I want to achieve my solution only using Okta as OIDC provider and don't want to use Okta + AWS Cognito.

My identities are in Okta and I want to generate JWT at userlogon in AWS Okta. I will then use this JWT to assume a role in AWS as mentioned in doc [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-idp_oidc.html#idp_oidc_Prerequisites) and return STS creds using API call [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html).
Please let me know how can I achieve this. Please provide your response in a simple way with example as I am new to Okta and Identity world. Please feel free to correct me if I am missing something conceptually.

P.S: I am passing this JWT token in a POST request to APIGW which then passes it to Lambda. I am doing some stuff with Lambda with this JWT token. Right now I am using Okta + AWS Cognito. But want to get rid of Cognito unless necessary.

Solution to above ask

I want below Solution Workflow:

1. User logs in to Okta portal using userid and password and gets authenticated. Identities in Okta re from multiple identity sources.
2. JWT token is generated after logon.
3. Capture JWT Token and pass it to Lambda using by calling an API in APIGW using POST API call
4. Run [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html) call in Lambda to return STS creds in response. While running the call apply in session policy to scope down level of permissions depending on attributes passed in JWT token.The scope down policy is created in lambda based on dynamic attributes in JWT Token.
5. Scoped down temp creds are used by user to perform the action.

I am creating dynamic policies as this is a SAAS product and end users(vendors/finance users etc) will need temporary access depending on their role.

Currently, I am using Congnito in middle as per [link](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cognito-okta-oidc-identity-provider) but want to get rid of Cognito.

Comment: Okta works very well without AWS. In some part of your question you say not aws and in other parts you need aws role. Is not understandable. Tell us about your main requirement. Do you have the classic stack: web + several apis deployed in aws and you need a login with okta?

Comment: @JRichardsz I have added the solution workflow I need. Hope it helps to understand my problem. Pls let me know if need additional details.